# subfloatrow: centering single subfigure

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats

In the example below, how can I center the third figure (C)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \floatsetup{objectset=centering}
  \ffigbox{%
    \begin{subfloatrow}%
      \ffigbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
          \end{tikzpicture}}{\caption{A}}%
    \ffigbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
          \end{tikzpicture}}{\caption{B}}%
  \end{subfloatrow}
  \begin{subfloatrow}% 
    \ffigbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
          \end{tikzpicture}}{\caption{C}}%
      \end{subfloatrow}
}{\caption{}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

omitting the second subfloatrow gives me centering, however, I leave the subcaption numbering.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It seems centered to me...

Answer (score 1):

Figure C is centered to me. You can improve the code by using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \subfloat[][\emph{A}.]
        {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        } \qquad
    \subfloat[][\emph{B}.]
        {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        } \\
    \subfloat[][\emph{C}.]
        {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
\caption{Example.}
\label{fig:subfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```